# What is the the meaning and purpose of this unusual value in URL parameter?

Tags: php, http, security, querystringparameter

I am looking at my server logs and I see malicious requests like this:

```
http://www.*****.in/catalogue.php?storeid=%27nvOpzp;%20AND%201=1%20OR%20(%3C%27%22%3EiKO))
```

What is the user trying to do, and and how can I protect against such things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we urldecode the parameter value, it becomes a bit more readable and it's clear that it's a SQL injection attempt - the parameter becomes

```
Opzp; AND 1=1 OR (<'">iKO)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/apMJ7 .

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) if you're not familiar with how to guard against that sort of thing. Basically you need to use prepared statements and parameterise all variable values which you incorporate into your queries.